# How do you check if a firebase snapshot child has value true or false?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, snapshot

```
JSON
switch
  uid
    switch : true
  uid2
    switch : false
```

What I tried that doesn't work

```
 @objc func didLongPress() {


    let databaseRef = Database.database().reference().child("switch").child(self.postID)
databaseRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "switch").queryEqual(toValue: "true").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in               
   print(snapshot)
           if snapshot.exists() {
               print("Address is in DB")
             } else {
               print("Address doesn't exist")
             }
             }}
//////note it picks up self.postID successfully so error is after that. print snapshot gives null
```

also tried

```
   let databaseRef = Database.database().reference().child("switch").child(self.postID).child("switch/\true")
    databaseRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
            print(snapshot)
        if snapshot.exists() {
            print("Address is in DB")
          } else {
            print("Address doesn't exist")
          }
            }
}
```

So in theory this should be a really easy, elementary task. The first of the above mentioned attempts should work. There are no permission errors, but console simply produce null as the snapshot print. That is so weird.

If I test a simple snapshot to see what prints with `.child(switch).child(self.postID).child(switch)` - it prints either 1 for true and 0 for false. So that works.

EDIT: I think this is because it is in an objective c function. I just realized that. I need it in objective C, because if gets called on long press, which uses objective c function

Comment: This reads like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to accomplish? 1) Find UID nodes for which the `switch` property has a value `true`? 2) Checking whether `switch` is `true` for a specific, known UID node?

Comment: The latter. Once a user's pic is clicked, it checks if he or she has value true or false

Comment: The issue is with your query and I am linking [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66369723/how-do-you-call-a-firebase-snapshot-in-objective-c-instead-of-swift) because the answer will end up being the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

(Change database child path as per your need.)

```
Database.database().reference().child("switch").child(self.postID).queryOrdered(byChild: "switch").queryEqual(toValue: true).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
     if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
         print("Address is in DB")
     } else {
         print("Address doesn't exist")
     }
}) { (error) in
     print(error.localizedDescription)
   }
```

Comment: thanks will try. I hope it works inside the ObjC function. I realized earlier that might be the issue

Comment: no unfortunately it acts the same as my attempt

Comment: Can you tell me more about your problem?