# How do you call a firebase snapshot in Objective C instead of swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, snapshot

```
JSON
switch
  uid
    switch : true
  uid2
    switch : false
```

Update: above is the database structure, which I added after Jay's comment.

In swift I would do:

```
    let databaseRef = Database.database().reference().child("switch").child(self.postID)
databaseRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "switch").queryEqual(toValue: "true").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in               
 print(snapshot)
            if snapshot.exists() {
                print("Address is in DB")
              } else {
                print("Address doesn't exist")
              }
                }
```

But I have to use Objective C because I have to use an Objective C selector

```
   @objc func didLongPress() {

 ///that snapshot
 }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
     super.awakeFromNib()
        let longPress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didLongPress))
            like.addGestureRecognizer(longPress)
    }
```

Update: Possible solution?

```
       let ref = Database.database().reference().child("switch").child(self.postID).child("switch")
    ref.observeSingleEvent(of:.value,  with: {snapshot in
         if snapshot.exists() {
            print("Got data \(snapshot.value!)") //will print true or false
            let ab = snapshot.value!
            if ab as! Int>0 {
                print("yes")
            } else {
                print("no")
            }
        }
        else {
            print("No data available")
        }
    })
```

Comment: The Firebase documentation shows example of Objective C code too: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#objective-c_3

Comment: Thanks. I'll try. But where to you add `@property (strong, nonatomic) FIRDatabaseReference *ref; ` for the swift equivalent `var ref: DatabaseReference!`

Comment: Don't confuse the Objc selector with the actual code to interact with firebase. You can certainly use Swift along with @ objc. When you apply @ objc to a class or method within a Swift project, it will make those available to Objective-C as well as Swift code. The problem looks to be with your query; it's running against a child node `switch` and then querying on a child node `switch` which doesn't look right.

Comment: Also, when posting Firebase questions, including your structure is critical so we can see what you're attempting to do. So, update your question with your structure, as text please, no images. To get your Firebase structure, use the Firebase console->Export JSON and copy and paste a snippet of your structure.

Comment: @Jay thanks. That is very weird. So I should be able to use the swift code within the objective c function. I added the DB structure. I don't think the issue is with the child having the same name. I also tested this with the 2nd switch child being named switch1

Comment: Yes, you can use Swift. The issue is with the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with the query.  Here's the structure from the question

```
JSON
switch
  uid
    switch : true
  uid2
    switch : false
```

and the query being used is querying the following

```
your_database
   switch
      uid
         switch: true --> the query is running against this single child node <--
      uid2
         the query is NOT running here
```

There's really no reason to run a query against a single child node if you know the path. If the purpose is to determine if that child exists, there's no need for query at all. Just read the node directly and see if it exists

```
let ref = your_database.child("switch").child(self.postID).child("switch")
ref.observeSingleEvent...
```

and if switch is present with any value (true or false) it will be returned in the snapshot.

**EDIT**

If you want to know the value of the child, it will be in the snapshot if it exists. Here's some code

```
let ref = your_database.child("switch").child(self.postID).child("switch")
ref.getData { (error, snapshot) in
    if let error = error {
        print("Error getting data \(error)")
    }
    else if snapshot.exists() {
        let myBool = snapshot.value as? Bool ?? false
        print("Got data \(myBool)") //will print true or false
    }
    else {
        print("No data available")
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks. But I need to know if it is true or false. If it is true, I am going to display something, and if it is false, something else. I tried that format  `let ref = your_database.child("switch").child(self.postID).child("switch")`
 yesterday with `if snapshot.isEqual(true)` and it didn't work

Comment: @uuuuuu The value will be in the snapshot (as mentioned in my answer) if it exists; true or false. This `if snapshot.isEqual(true)` is not valid and will not work. Probably a good idea to see the documentation [Read Data Once](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#read_data_once) so you can read the firebase child value. I added an Edit to my answer as a solution.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. Printing true or false is a good start. I just need to execute different code depending on if it is true of false. In the `else if` , could I then use something like:  `if snapshot.value! == true...`?

Comment: also is getData not a storage call. Error says `Value of type 'DatabaseReference' has no member 'getData'`

Comment: @uuuuuu Have you reviewed the documentation I linked? This question is not about [Firebase Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage), we are using the Realtime Database and `getData` is explained in the documentation. You can see from my example you can get the value to `true` or `false` so within that else statement you can add whatever code you want to take action based on that value. You're coding journey will be much smoother if you refer to the docs and ensure your code and podfiles are up-to-date.

Comment: Yes, that for the documentation. It didn't document why I'd be getting the error ` Value of type 'DatabaseReference' has no member 'getData'`, so I googled it and saw that getData() is used with storage. Do you know what pod causes this. I do terminal pod update every now and then. Last was 2 weeks ago I think

Comment: @uuuuuu Please see the link Read Data Once in my above comment as that is the correct documentation for getData - it's used with the Realtime Database for this situation. You may have have an outdated Firebase API so update your Firebase.

Comment: by update firebase, do you mean pod firebase needs to be updated? I just hit pod update in terminal.Geofire updated but all the others were up to date.

Comment: @uuuuuu If everything is up-to-date the code in my answer will not cause an error and is the solution. It works correctly - I took it out of a working project.

Comment: I did pod reintegrate and then pod install. I cleared build folder, deleted derived data among other things. Still gives error `Value of type 'DatabaseReference' has no member 'getData'` This is truly very weird.

Comment: I am not getting it to work, so I tried something else. Do you concur that it is an acceptable solution? I'll mark yours as correct anyway as it does correspond with the firebase documentation. I added my possible solution in the question

Comment: @uuuuuu If the solution works then it's acceptable. I made an error in my answer in that it won't print true or false - it will print 1 or 0 so I corrected that so now it will print true or false. You don't need to this `if ab as! Int>0` if you cast the value to a bool - you can then work with it as true or false. See the edited code.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for the help